# Error Loading Assemblies in Mono for android

Tags: xamarin.android

Mono for android was working just fine but after a pc restart I get the following error for my project? The error title is just "Error Loading Assemblies" and the details are in the image below.

[image]

Any idea what could be the cause? This is happening in monodroid 4.2.2 and it happens both on emulator and a physcal android:

Comment: I'd log this as a bug on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi - the team should reply pretty quickly to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through xamarin forum I found that cleaning the solution in Visual Studio will fix this problem. Hope this helps somone else.